openzeppelin 5.0.x TransparentUpgradeableProxy upgradeAndCall error
I'm writing a Solidity deploy script using Foundry. TransparentUpgradeableProxy upgradeAndCall error
openzeppelin: 5.0.x

deploy all contracts

https://github.com/WarriorFromLongAgo/fishcake-contracts/blob/main/script/Deployer.s.sol

I'm executing the deploy using this command:

forge script script/Deployer.s.sol:DeployerScript --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:8545/ --private-key $env:PRIVATE_KEY --broadcast -vvvvv


Upgrade InvestorSalePool contract

https://github.com/WarriorFromLongAgo/fishcake-contracts/blob/main/script/UpgradeInvestorSalePoolDeployer.s.sol

I'm executing the deploy using this command:

forge script script/UpgradeInvestorSalePoolDeployer.s.sol:UpgradeInvestorSalePoolDeployer --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:8545 --private-key $env:PRIVATE_KEY --broadcast -vvvv


error log

== Logs ==
  New InvestorSalePool implementation deployed at: 0x0613c549d358fB743037bE6De52E4348AdA96Ad0
  proxyAdmin  deployed at: 0x5094103dE460dF9BC1A0F2D69d6D6547cc97c050
  proxyAdmin owner deployed at: 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720
  deployerAddress deployed at: 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720
  run 1 msg.sender deployed at: 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720
Error:
script failed: <empty revert data>


error stack

Traces:
  [2125496] → new UpgradeInvestorSalePoolDeployer@0x5b73C5498c1E3b4dbA84de0F1833c4a029d90519
    └─ ← [Return] 10395 bytes of code

  [1458402] UpgradeInvestorSalePoolDeployer::run()
    ├─ [0] VM::envUint("PRIVATE_KEY") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] VM::addr(<pk>) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720
    ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast(<pk>)
    │   └─ ← [Return]
    ├─ [1394180] → new InvestorSalePool@0x0613c549d358fB743037bE6De52E4348AdA96Ad0
    │   ├─ emit Initialized(version: 18446744073709551615 [1.844e19])
    │   └─ ← [Return] 6821 bytes of code
    ├─ [0] console::log("New InvestorSalePool implementation deployed at:", InvestorSalePool: [0x0613c549d358fB743037bE6De52E4348AdA96Ad0]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [0] console::log("proxyAdmin  deployed at:", 0x5094103dE460dF9BC1A0F2D69d6D6547cc97c050) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [2298] 0x5094103dE460dF9BC1A0F2D69d6D6547cc97c050::owner() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720
    ├─ [0] console::log("proxyAdmin owner deployed at:", 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [0] console::log("deployerAddress deployed at:", 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [298] 0x5094103dE460dF9BC1A0F2D69d6D6547cc97c050::owner() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720
    ├─ [0] console::log("run 1 msg.sender deployed at:", 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [9510] 0x5094103dE460dF9BC1A0F2D69d6D6547cc97c050::upgradeAndCall(0x0D8694F47cDC22Bb8C6D2668a38d07a439F378F9, InvestorSalePool: [0x0613c549d358fB743037bE6De52E4348AdA96Ad0], 0xc4d66de8000000000000000000000000a0ee7a142d267c1f36714e4a8f75612f20a79720)
    │   ├─ [5568] 0x0D8694F47cDC22Bb8C6D2668a38d07a439F378F9::upgradeToAndCall(InvestorSalePool: [0x0613c549d358fB743037bE6De52E4348AdA96Ad0], 0xc4d66de8000000000000000000000000a0ee7a142d267c1f36714e4a8f75612f20a79720)
    │   │   ├─ [696] 0xA922C3227149D9bc5001D796aA418b590D0C4a7B::upgradeToAndCall(InvestorSalePool: [0x0613c549d358fB743037bE6De52E4348AdA96Ad0], 0xc4d66de8000000000000000000000000a0ee7a142d267c1f36714e4a8f75612f20a79720) [delegatecall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert
    │   │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert
    │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert
    └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert


https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/5-0-transparentupgradeableproxy-upgradeandcall-error/41540
In the openzeppelin forum, I found the answer.

Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! A user flagged this answer. Please review and edit your answer to avoid deletions https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer
